# Ansible lineinfile give an error with /etc/hosts

Tags: provisioning, ansible

I have this simple task in my role:

```
- name: Updating the /etc/hosts
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts line="192.168.99.100  {{ item }}"
  with_items: 
    - domain1.com
    - domain2.com
  tags: etc
```

When I run my Ansible playbook:

```
robe:ansible-develop robe$ ansible-playbook -i inventory develop-env.yml -vvvv --extra-vars "user=`whoami`" --tags etc --become-user=robe --ask-become-pass
SUDO password: 

PLAY [127.0.0.1] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154 && echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154']
<127.0.0.1> PUT /var/folders/x1/dyrdksh50tj0z2szv3zx_9rc0000gq/T/tmpMYjnXz TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154/setup
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154/setup']
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=rqphpqfpcbsifqtnwflmmlmpwrcnkpqe] password: " -u robe /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-rqphpqfpcbsifqtnwflmmlmpwrcnkpqe; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154/setup'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'rm -rf /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.27-256837595805154/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [docker-tool-box | Updating the /etc/hosts] ***************************** 
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE lineinfile dest=/etc/hosts line="192.168.99.100 ptxrt.com"
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893 && echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893']
<127.0.0.1> PUT /var/folders/x1/dyrdksh50tj0z2szv3zx_9rc0000gq/T/tmpyLOGd6 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893/lineinfile
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893/lineinfile']
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=nofwziqxytbhjwhluhtzdfcqclqjuypv] password: " -u robe /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-nofwziqxytbhjwhluhtzdfcqclqjuypv; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893/lineinfile'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'rm -rf /tmp/ansible-tmp-1446050161.49-9492873099893/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=ptxrt.com) => {"failed": true, "item": "ptxrt.com"}
msg: The destination directory (/private/etc) is not writable by the current user.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/robe/develop-env.retry

127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I don't understand why the error msg said:

```
 msg: The destination directory (/private/etc) is not writable by the current user.
```

The correct directory should be /etc/hosts.

Any clue?

**I am working on MacOS.**

### My playbook is:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "{{user}}"
  roles:
    - role-1
    - role-2
```

I put the become_user by command line. So all my roles are running with become. And it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX the `/etc/` folder is actually a symlink to the `/private/etc/` folder - hence the error. (Ansible is just transparently following the symlink).

As for the error you're going to need to run the task with `become: yes` (sudo permissions) to be able to write to `/etc/hosts/`

*Edit based on update and commments*

To get the correct privileges to edit the hosts file you need to be root. Setting `become: yes` on the task is good enough for this for OSX as Ansible will default to sudo as the `become` method and `root` as the user.

To specify the sudo password you can do one of two things.

1. Use `--ask-become-pass` on the command line and Ansible will prompt you when it needs it
2. Use the `ansible_become_pass` variable on the group or host in the inventory file. E.g. `localhost ansible_become_pass=batman`

Note that the Ansible docs recommend against 2 and using 1 so as not to store your password in plain text.

Comment: I update my question @Woodham. I don't know where the problems is? Is possible to run this on local?

Comment: Are you getting a new error when using become?  You should just need the. `become: yes` line. Not the user or method one.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the command line options you're using. You're using  your local user as your sudo user. You need to sudo to root.

Comment: ok, I removed all become_VARIABLE and only ```used become: yes``` and it works. But I had to keep my ```--ask-become-pass```. Is possible to set the pass inside the code and not in the command line? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: If you add to your answer the other tips about remove the become_user and become_method I can accept your answer. :)